# Ubuntu 20.04 infected with nood rat malware, clamav is coming back clean. Does anyone know how to manually clean this?

Tags: 20.04, webserver, malware

Ubuntu 20.04 is infected with nood rat malware, ClamAV is coming back clean.  Does anyone have the process for manual cleaning this?

Comment: How do you see this "malware" ?

Comment: There's some information and advice in [this content](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/nood-virus/)